# BigQuery: extract keys from json object, convert json from object to key-value array

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

I have a table with a column which contains a json-object,  the value type is always a string.

I need 2 kind of information:

- a list of the json keys
- convert the json in an array of key-value pairs

This is what I got so far, which is working:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION jsonObjectKeys(input STRING)
RETURNS Array<String>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
""";

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION jsonToKeyValueArray(input STRING)
RETURNS Array<Struct<key String, value String>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  let json = JSON.parse(input);
  return Object.keys(json).map(e => {
    return { "key" : e, "value" : json[e] }
  });
""";

WITH input AS (
  SELECT "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}" AS json_column
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key3\": \"value3\"}" AS json_column
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "{\"key5\": \"value5\"}" AS json_column
)

SELECT
  json_column,
  jsonObjectKeys(json_column) AS keys,
  jsonToKeyValueArray(json_column) AS key_value
FROM input
```

The problem is that `FUNCTION` is not the best in term of compute optimization, so I'm trying to understand if there is a way to use plain SQL to achieve these 2 needs (or 1 of them at least) using only SQL w/o functions.

Answer (score 9):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardsql
select
  json_column,
  array(select trim(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)]) from t.kv kv) as keys,
  array(
    select as struct 
      trim(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)]) as key, 
      trim(split(kv, ':')[offset(1)]) as value
    from t.kv kv
  ) as key_value
from input, 
unnest([struct(split(translate(json_column, '{}"', '')) as kv)]) t
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Yes it works very well thank you - I am surprised BQ doesn't have a utility function for this

Comment: Could it be that this function fails if keys/values contain colons and/or if values are arrays of strings (i.e., contain the `"` character)?

Comment: sure, if you have such edge case and need help - post your question and we will help

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I am trying to decode this but am struggling. On line `array(select trim(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)]) from t.kv kv) as keys` what does t.kv kv mean? is t = dataset, kv = column?

Comment: is there another way to do the `UNNEST` operation? that is supported by BQ materialized views