# How can I only get keys from an array in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an event table in BigQuery. I have two columns: event_name and event_parameters. I need to export parameter keys.

I'm looking for something similar to

```
dict.keys()
```

from pyton.

for example:

| event_name | event_parameters |
| --- | --- |
| event_a | {"from": "main_page","ID":"123"} |
| event_b | {"ID":"242","custom_value":"true" |

output table:

| event_name | event_parameters |
| --- | --- |
| event_a | {"from","ID"} |
| event_b | {"ID","custom_value" |

Comment: have you tried an< json functions yet?

Comment: I've heard it for the first time.

Comment: You can use an UDF and other  approach.  see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74087977/how-to-parse-json-with-dynamic-key-in-bigquery  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65048929/bigquery-extract-keys-from-json-object-convert-json-from-object-to-key-value-a

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the keys from a json column using the following SQL code as a template:

```
WITH data AS(
SELECT '{"from":"main_page","ID":"123"}' AS params
)

SELECT keys from(
  select
    params,
    array(select trim(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)]) from t.kv kv) as keys,
    array(
      select as struct 
        trim(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)]) as key, 
        trim(split(kv, ':')[offset(1)]) as value
      from t.kv kv
    ) as key_value
  from data, 
  unnest([struct(split(translate(params, '{}"', '')) as kv)]) t
)
```

Credit to @Mikhail Berlyant for providing the original code for the following solution:
[BigQuery: extract keys from json object, convert json from object to key-value array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65048929/bigquery-extract-keys-from-json-object-convert-json-from-object-to-key-value-a)